# Validate XML with Nifi

Tags: xml, validation, apache-nifi

What is the proper way to validate an XML file with Nifi processors?

Is there an example of a schema for the validteXML processor?

I am new to the Nifi world.

Comment: just look for the `xsd` file examples over the internet and how to create them. also there are some online `xsd` schema generators by xml file: https://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html